# Spotlight Search: Show ALL FILES, and exclude ALL FOLDERS

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

I am looking for a macOS equivalent of the Windows command:

```
type:NOT"file folder"
```

This command, when entered into Windows Explorer search bar, will display all the files of a directory or hard drive, without showing the folders in the search results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Spotlight query you need to use the "kind" attribute.  The search term you want is:

```
"search term" NOT kind:folder
```

For example, I tested this looking for an eBook titled ***Mastering OpenVPN***.  Here are the results of the two searches:

[image]
[image]

#### Kind Keywords for Spotlight Search

[image: Spotlight Kind Search Terms]

<sup>I don't recall where I obtained this list; I just have it saved in my notes as plain text. I formatted it as an image for this site because there was no facility to create a table here on Ask Different</sup>

Comment: This is really cool.  I didn’t know that this type of search was possible. Thanks for the keyword list, its really helpful!  

Comment: more info including date filter: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15155/11.0/mac/11.0