# Spotlight Recursive Search in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search

How do I have a recursive search for filetypes in a Finder folder?

- no AppleScript
- no Terminal
- 100% Spotlight

Is this possible?  Looking for `mp3` and `jpg` file types.  I am using El Capitan (macOS 10.10)

Answer (score 3):

#### Spotlight Search

Use the `kind` attribute in your Spotlight search.  For example, in the search dialog, type

`kind:mp3`

to find all MP3 files.  I have a listing of all the relevant attributes in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/400405/119271).

So, for a more relevant example, you would issue a Spotlight search with your search term in double quotes and specify the attribute as follows:

`"search term" kind:mp3`

---

#### Not indexed by Spotlight

If you have a location not indexed by Spotlight, the most efficient tool for doing this is the built in tool `find`, however, since "Terminal" is off the table, you're options are limited.

- **Use Finder Search** <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and create a query for that specific location.  Here's an example of a Finder search for images in my "Backgrounds" folder (and below)

  [image: Finder Image Search]
- **Use a 3rd party tool.**  *Disclaimer:  There are many tools out there, but the good ones will usually have a cost. These are the ones I'm familiar with however, they are not what I use as I prefer to utilize built in tools like `find`, `mdfind` and even `locate` via the command line.*

  - [HoudahSpot 5](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/) ($35USD) Allows you to create and save complex search queries on macOS.
  - [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) (Free, but Powerpack is about $40USD).  This is more of a productivity and workflow tool, but it does have excellent search capabilities.  The Powerpak can greatly enhance all of the functions.
  - [Find Any File](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/find-any-file-faf/id402569179?mt=12) ($8USD).  A search utility that goes beyond Spotlight.
  - [EasyFind](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfinder-2/id1531238115?mt=12) ($0). File search utility that helps organize your searching.   Recommended by user [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

Comment: I just realized this folder is on a volume that isn't in Spotlight.

Comment: If it's not indexed by Spotlight, Spotlight won't find it.  Do you want to know how to index it or do you want a different method to search?

Comment: I was under the assumption it was indexed.  Then I remembered after I posted.  I know how to search other ways.  I wanted the Finder to do it.

Comment: Also [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware)

Comment: I didn't know about that one @Tetsujin - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do a recursive search in Finder using Spotlight.

I just forgot to make sure that Spotlight had indexed the volume I was trying to search.

I removed this volume from the Privacy tab in System Preferences > Spotlight, and now I can search it recursively with Finder.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question? Please edit to clarify the meaning of this post if it is indeed an answer, or edit the original question if it was meant to be an amendment to the question.

Comment: Is that good enough for you?  I won't draw any pictures.

Comment: It may explain why you were confused, but it doesn't actually answer the question as asked.

Comment: It answers it completely.  You simply cannot do what I want without having it in Spotlight.  It's not in Spotlight because it was in my Privacy tab in the Spotlight preferences.  Take it out and it gets into Spotlight.

Comment: @Rich_F before asking the question, did you know that Spotlight/Finder normally supports this?

Comment: @theonlygusti Supports what?  Spotlight index everything unless you put it into Privacy.  I didn't realize the directory I was searching in, was in the Privacy directory.

Comment: @Rich_F then your question should have been "spotlight recursive search mysteriously not working for certain directory", you (apparently knowingly) asked an X/Y question.

Comment: @theonlygusti Wrong.  First off, the question was about recursive searches.  You can't recursively search something that you don't know isn't indexed.  I can't recursively search it now as I can't put it into Spotlight.  I have realized since asking that it was not indexed.  You should read what I put in the comments.

Comment: Just FYI...Spotlight does an indexed search, not recursive.  It's assumed when you say "recursive search" you mean *directory recursion* - searching the directory and all child directories.  The Finder search (Cmd-F) would be closest to that.  You really only need to specify recursion when operating on the command line.

Comment: @Allan Since it was not indexed, I couldn't check.  I didn't know if it went deeper.  Yes I meant directory recursion.  -R.  I remember running into this issue before, and could have been the same non-Spotlight issue on that directory as well.